# Magento New Registration Form for Wholesalers

Tags: forms, magento

We would like to have two registration pages one for `retailers` and one for `wholesalers`.

```
customer/account/create/
```

&

```
customer/account/create/wholesale/
```

how to make this happen in Magento?

Answer (score 2):

> **You can add your wholesaler registration using this code**.

1) [A New registration form for wholesalers customer](http://midpart.wordpress.com/2011/02/17/a-new-registration-form-for-wholesale-customer/)

2) [wholesalers signup For magento store](http://www.nextbits.eu/blog/how-to-add-wholesale-signup-in-magento-store/)

Comment: add to your register.phtml file 
<input type="hidden" name="form_key" value="<?php echo Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->getFormKey() ?>" />

this is required since mangento 1.9.2 - which i guess you are using if the above tutorials don't work for you